# How to save data from a tuple object in Python?

Tags: python, django, tuples

I am facing this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'
```

from the following piece of code:

```
def load_images_to_db(path):
  for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
      subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
      label = Label.get_or_create(name=subdirname)
      label.save()
```

The error comes from this line: `label.save()`
Someone can help ?

Comment: What are you expecting `save()` to do? Save it where?

Comment: What is `Label` here?.(Note: `Label.get_or_create` returns a `tuple` here)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM     
label is a table from my db

Comment: Err... I don't mean to be rude but this is clearly documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_or_create()` returns a tuple. You do not have to explicitly call `save()`

Use

```
label, created = Label.get_or_create(name=subdirname)
```

- `created` will return if a new object is saved to DB
- `label` will return you the object that was saved.

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)**